# How to select based on (multiple) values while reading a .csv in chunks in R

Tags: r, for-loop, bigdata, gis, chunking

I have a ~26 GB file of 25 years of climate data, which is much too large to handle in R. The variables are:
    year (X1992),
    month (X7) ,
    metric (tave)
    conus (conus)
    latitude (X24.5625) ,
    longitude (X81.8125) ,
    measurement (X29.49).

```
head(df.laf)
     X1992 X7  tave conus  X24.5625  X.81.8125 X29.49
1    1992  7   tave conus  24.5625   -81.7708  29.46
```

50 rows of sample data:

> dput(droplevels(head(data,50)))

```
structure(list(year = c(1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 
1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 
1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 
1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 
1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 
1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L), month = c(7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L), metric = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "tave", class = "factor"), 
conus = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "conus", class = "factor"), 
latitude = c(24.5625, 24.5625, 24.5625, 24.5625, 24.6042, 
24.6458, 24.6458, 24.6875, 24.6875, 24.7292, 24.7708, 25.1458, 
25.1458, 25.1458, 25.1458, 25.1458, 25.1458, 25.1458, 25.1458, 
25.1458, 25.1875, 25.1875, 25.1875, 25.1875, 25.1875, 25.1875, 
25.1875, 25.1875, 25.1875, 25.1875, 25.1875, 25.1875, 25.1875, 
25.1875, 25.2292, 25.2292, 25.2292, 25.2292, 25.2292, 25.2292, 
25.2292, 25.2292, 25.2292, 25.2292, 25.2292, 25.2292, 25.2292, 
25.2292, 25.2292, 25.2292), longitude = c(-81.8125, -81.7708, 
-81.7292, -81.6875, -81.6458, -81.5625, -81.4792, -81.5625, 
-81.3958, -81.3958, -80.9375, -81.1042, -81.0625, -81.0208, 
-80.9792, -80.9375, -80.7708, -80.7292, -80.4375, -80.3958, 
-81.1042, -81.0625, -81.0208, -80.9792, -80.9375, -80.8958, 
-80.8542, -80.8125, -80.7708, -80.7292, -80.6875, -80.6042, 
-80.3958, -80.3542, -81.1458, -81.1042, -81.0625, -81.0208, 
-80.8958, -80.8542, -80.8125, -80.7708, -80.7292, -80.6875, 
-80.6458, -80.6042, -80.5625, -80.5208, -80.4792, -80.4375
), measurement = c(29.49, 29.46, 29.41, 29.38, 29.39, 29.33, 
29.33, 29.28, 29.27, 29.22, 29.09, 28.83, 28.82, 28.76, 28.7, 
28.64, 28.55, 28.58, 28.51, 28.52, 28.72, 28.67, 28.66, 28.7, 
28.64, 28.58, 28.62, 28.56, 28.54, 28.54, 28.58, 28.51, 28.47, 
28.48, 28.87, 28.67, 28.76, 28.76, 28.58, 28.47, 28.4, 28.4, 
28.34, 28.38, 28.37, 28.46, 28.52, 28.52, 28.52, 28.48)), .Names = c("year", 
"month", "metric", "conus", "latitude", "longitude", "measurement"),
row.names = c(NA, 50L), class = "data.frame")
```

The dataset represents climate data for the entire U.S. I am only interested in analyzing a particular region. To get the file down to a manageable size, I want to read it into R in chunks, while filtering based on longitude/latitude values.

Below is the code I used to 1) read in chunks of 1^e6 using (LaF) and 2) filter based on latitude (column name "X24.5625") value of 42.3542 using a for loop.

When I run this code, the resulting df (res) reveals a table with "No data available in table". Ultimately, my goal is to write a for loop that successfully returns a table with specified longitude/latitude values, and iterates this over every row in the dataset in chunks of 1e^6 rows.

My question is:

1) why am I getting an empty table, rather than a table with values that correspond to the specified latitude?
2) how can I make sure for loop runs over the entire dataset?

I am a new R user and would benefit from annotated code if possible.

```
#read dataframe in chunks
library('LaF')
quatcent <- '1972_2017.csv'

#create column names
quatcent_colnames <- c("year", "month", "metric", "conus", "latitude", 
"longitude", "measurement")

#detect a model for file:
model <- detect_dm_csv(quatcent, sep=",", header=TRUE)

#create connection to file using model:
df.laf <- laf_open(model)

# go to a specified place in the file (in this case, row 1)
goto(df.laf, 1)
data <- next_block(df.laf,nrows=1e6)
names(data) <-
c("year","month","metric","conus","latitude","longitude","measurement")


# create a for loop to subset by long/lat value
library('dplyr')
library('stringr')

res <- df.laf[1,][0,]
for(i in 1:10){
  raw <-
    next_block(df.laf,nrows=100e6) %>% 
    filter(str_detect("X24.5625","42.3542"))
  res <- rbind(res, raw)

}
```

Comment: It's probably a good idea to post sample data here using `dput`. 50 lines should do it. You can try to read in blocks of 10 lines just to see if your code works

Comment: Plus your code would be very slow as you're trying to grow `res` within that `for` loop. More info here http://r-statistics.co/Strategies-To-Improve-And-Speedup-R-Code.html

Comment: http://winvector.github.io/Accumulation/

Comment: thanks - sample data added

Comment: I recommend using sed or awk or write a small c program to read the file and extract the desired rows and columns into a new file and using R on that file. One advantage is that you don't have to keep reading the large file every time you want to do some processing on the subset. Using a c program will also allow you to write the output file using int or long or float or double that will reduce the size of the output file even more.

Comment: Slightly less sophisticated but maybe easier: Export the lat/lons of one year of data into a GIS (like QGIS or ArcGIS) and select the region you're interested in. The data probably reads from left to right, bottom to top, so by knowing the number of your selected point in the grid, together with the known number of observations per grid point (do you know them?) you can calculate the starting point for reading in the csv file.